# ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[Storage -> Storage -> Storage]: Ionic 4

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

Launching my Ionic app via npm start, I get this error

> "NullInjectorError: No provider for Storage!".

I have included Storage in app.module.ts like this:

```
imports: \[
BrowserModule,
IonicModule.forRoot(),
AppRoutingModule,
IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
HttpClientModule,
ModalPayConfirmationPageModule,
ModalAlergenPageModule
\],
```

I'm using Ionic 4. If someone could help me I would be grateful.

I've reinstalled Storage, Ionic and even removed and added  `IonicStorageModule.forRoot()` in app.module.ts

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide Storage in your app.module.ts

```
imports: [...],
providers: [Storage]
```

You could also put your service in root.

```
Injectable({ providIn: 'root' })
```

Comment: Now it shows error Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for Storage: (?), when I add Storage to Providers